# Decode() in Oracle

Tags: oracle, decode

What is the syntax for decode() function of oracle to encrypt string in
Example :- if i want to encrypt 'suvendu' with'***' and 'mohan' with '$$$' for column fname of samples table

```
desc samples
Name   Null     Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
EMP_ID          VARCHAR2(20) 
LNAME           CHAR(10)     
FNAME           CHAR(20)     
DEPT            CHAR(20)     
SAL    NOT NULL NUMBER(12,2) 
H_DATE          DATE         
EMAIL           VARCHAR2(20) 
DESG            VARCHAR2(25)
```

Comment: The syntax of DECODE is of course explained in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions057.htm#SQLRF00631). What do you want to do exactly and why does it has to be done with DECODE?

Comment: DECODE(); works like (if 2nd parameter matches, replaces it with the 3rd parameter) and (if 4th parameter matches, replaces it with the 5th parameter) and so on.....e.g. SELECT DECODE(SAL, 1, "One", 2, "Two", 99, "ninetyNine") FROM samples

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `DECODE` to handle this, as in:

```
SELECT DECODE(FNAME,
                'suvendu', '***',
                'mohan',   '$$$',
                           FNAME) AS DERIVED_COL
  FROM SAMPLES
```

IMO using a CASE expression is a better choice

```
SELECT CASE FNAME
         WHEN 'suvendu' THEN '***'
         WHEN 'mohan'   THEN '$$$'
         ELSE FNAME
       END AS DERIVED_COL
  FROM SAMPLES
```

as it makes it clearer what's going on and is easier to read.

Best of luck.

Comment: Good suggestion/reminder that the _CASE_ is a good alternate expression!

Comment: Thanks dude its working,plz try answering my other question

Comment: dude case when is working but when i tried SELECT DECODE(FNAME,
                'suvendu', '***',
                'mohan',   '$$$',
                           FNAME) AS DERIVED_COL
  FROM SAMPLES i got  "missing expression" error

Answer (score 0):

Updated(try this):

```
SELECT 
    DECODE(fname,'suvendu', '***', 'mohan", '$$$') AS F_NAME
    --add other columns/column-list here if needed
FROM 
    samples
```

The line starting with -- is a commented line

Comment: when i execute the query i am getting the below error

Comment: "FROM keyword not found where expected" this is the error which i got

Comment: @suvendu , try it now